# Order Statistics; Finding the probability that the first sample is < 0.6, and the last sample is > 0.6

Tags: self-study, density-function, cumulative-distribution-function, order-statistics

Here is the problem statement below:

A random sample of size 5 is drawn from the pdf $f_Y(y)=2y, 0\le y \le1$. Calculate $P(Y_1^{'} < 0.6 < Y_5^{'})$.

Here, using formulas for order statistics I was able to calculate that $P(Y_1^{'} < 0.6)$ is about $0.892$, and $P(Y_5^{'} < 0.6)$ is about $0.006$.

I thought to get the answer, I could subtract $P(Y_5^{'} < 0.6) - P(Y_1^{'} < 0.6)$.

Why doesn't this work?

(the way to calculate this is actually to take $1-[P(Y_1^{'} > 0.6)+P(Y_5^{'} < 0.6)]$, but not sure why.

Comment: Calculate the chance that this event does *not* happen.  Hint: that can occur in two *disjoint* ways: the maximum is less than $0.6$ or the minimum exceeds $0.6.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is that you assumed that the second comparsion in $P(Y_1^{'} < 0.6 < Y_5^{'})$ is   $P(Y_5^{'} < 0.6)$. However, it's actually $P(0.6 < Y_5^{'})$ or  $P(Y_5^{'} \geq 0.6)$.

So, you can rewrite $P(Y_5^{'} \geq 0.6)$ as $1-P(Y_5^{'} < 0.6)$.

Comment: Thank you so much! So should this have been $P(Y_1^{'} \le 0.6 \le Y_5^{'})$, could I have done it that way? ($P(Y_5^{'} < 0.6)-P(Y_1^{'} < 0.6)$)

Comment: I'm sorry I think I'm getting confused. Let me read through it again. Thank you

Comment: Your general approach was right, you just confused $P(0.6 < Y_5^{'})$ with $P( Y_5^{'} < 0.6)$, because it looked like you regarded those two as the same

Comment: **To see why this answer cannot be correct,** consider what it leads to when 0.6 is replaced by a number $t$ close to $1:$ in that case both $P(Y_1^\prime \lt t)$ and $P(Y_5^\prime \lt t)$ will approach $1,$ yielding a *negative* probability for the answer!

Comment: yeah I agree, that obviously doesn't work

Comment: Unfortunately your edit still doesn't work: please closely review the passage starting "it's actually."  I have no doubt the argument is clear in your mind and correct, but currently you're not expressing it accurately.